# Date formula not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have columns containing separate values for Day, Month and Years which are formatted as general and contain no other formatting or formulas.

I'm trying to combine them using the `=DATE` formula in order to get proper date values, but it is giving me a #VALUE! error.

[image: error message]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use:

```
=DATE(C1,MONTH(DATEVALUE(A1&" 1")),B1)
```

Where you can convert month name to month value using `MONTH(DATEVALUE(A1&" 1"))`

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks. Do you know if there is a way to add the time on to the date? I've tried with `DATEVALUE(E1)+TIMEVALUE(D1)` but get another value error.

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. Just added the cells together (no `DATEVALUE` required) and formatted as date!

Answer (score 0):

Use `3` instead of writing `March` in column A.

Also check if your date format is set to `DATE(year,month,day)` in Home > Format > Format Cells>Date.

Ref: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATE-function-e36c0c8c-4104-49da-ab83-82328b832349